# Database host for wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm running a mysql database on my debian server, let's say it is [debian.server.com](http://debian.server.com) and I need to set it up for wordpress which is on another machine, let's say [mywordpress.com](http://mywordpress.com)

Now, I'm confused about what should I write here:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO "wordpressusername"@"hostname"
```

What would be `hostname` here?

And after that, how do I find out which is Database Host required for wp-config.php file?

Comment: IP (or domain for debian machine if mysql is accessible though that) for config, IP address of server with mywordpress.com in grant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hostname` should be set to the hostname/IP address from which the client is attempting to contact the database from. Examples:

```
127.0.0.1 => allows connecting from localhost
localhost => allows connecting from localhost
% => allows connecting from anywhere
192.168.0.123 => allows connecting from local network host 192.168.0.123
123.123.123.123 => allows connecting from host 123.123.123.123
```

`127.0.0.1` and `localhost` are different hostnames for MySQL so you need to match this to your `wp-config.php` if you're connecting from localhost.

You also need to setup MySQL to accept connections from outside the localhost or local network if needed.

Assuming you've configured your MySQL installation to accept connections and you have your database at 192.168.0.10 and your WordPress installation at 192.168.0.20 the following should work:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO "wordpressusername"@"192.168.0.20"
```

or

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO "wordpressusername"@"%"
```

The `wordpressusername` should match your WP setup in `wp-config.php` and the MySQL user should have the same password set in `wp-config.php` too.

**NOTE:** try not to use the `%` hostname marker. It allows a user to connect from *anywhere* so if the user's credentials were to be stolen you could have an open gate directly to the database from all around the world. So if at all possible use only full and direct IP addresses.

Comment: % is a horrible idea.

Comment: So, as a database host, only IP address of my server where the database is running, will be sufficient? No need for port or something else?

Comment: @Flyer Correct. I'll make a mention about that.

Comment: @hlamija if your MySQL is running on the default 3306 port no action regarding that should be needed. If not, then the `wp-config.php` `DB_HOST` value accepts `IP:port` notation if I remember correctly.